# an error while i try to merge cells together

Tags: excel, vba

I want to merge cells when the cells on the right is empty. My header starts at row 31. However, I faced a run time error 13 in the line "If ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 1), Cells(31, i)).Value = "" Then"

```
Sub mergingcells()
    Dim LastCellinArow As Long
    LastCellinArow = Cells(31, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print (LastCellinArow)
    For i = 1 To LastCellinArow
        If ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 1), Cells(31, i)).Value = "" Then
            Range("A31:AB31").Offset(-1, 0).Merge         
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

For example, if column j cells in row 31 is empty, I want to merge with column i cells in row 31.

Comment: What do you want accomplishing using this (wrong) code line: `If ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 1), Cells(31, i)).Value = "" Then`? If you need to check if there are no values in the range (only empty cells), you should use a different way. Try using `WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 1), Cells(31, i))) = 0 then`.

Comment: i want to check whether the cells in R31C9 is empty. If it is empty, then merge R31C8 and R31C9 together

Comment: I tried using WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(31, 1), Cells(31, i))) = 0 it works without errors but it didnt merge the cells together

Comment: But, what code do you use? You posted one piece of code which has a little logic, and after that you came with this one, which is at least strange... Do you want merging the cells of row 31:32 starting from column 1 up to the first column when the code find a filled cell? If yes, your fist code had some logic. Your existing code line `Range("A31:AB31").Offset(-1, 0).Merge` should be transformed in `Range(cells(31, 1), cells(31, i).Offset(-1, 0)).merge`

Comment: sflr, i just want to merge 2 cells together when the right cell in row 31 is empty. Merging R31C8 and R31C9 together to become a single cell.

Comment: OK. I will adapt your code to do what you say and post an answer in one, two minutes...

Answer (score 0):

please be sure that merged cells are same format. You may not merge cell with date format and cell with currency format

Comment: you have one brackets more ... just before  -  .Merge. Could you try without it.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub mergingcells()
    Dim LastCellinArow As Long, i As Long
    LastCellinArow = cells(31, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print (LastCellinArow)
    For i = 2 To LastCellinArow 'starting from 2 makes more sense...
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range(cells(31, 1), cells(31, i))) = 0 Then
            Range(cells(31, 1), cells(31, i)).merge 'it merges the left cell(s) with the next empty one
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @Chewjunnie: Does the sheet on which you run the code have some values on the row 31? What `Debug.Print (LastCellinArow)` does return in Immediate Window?

Comment: It returns the value of 28

Comment: @Chewjunnie: And are there **only** empty cells before column 28? If, for instance, you have a value in column A:A, nothing will be done, because the `CountA` will always return a long bigger then zero. If this is the case, you did not correctly explain what you want doing. Can you share the workbook you try testing? Or, at least, can you edit your question and place a picture with the existing situation and another one with what you want accomplishing?